# Is the Feast of First Fruits rather related to the Start or the End of the 50-day-count?

Tags: resurrection-of-jesus

I have seen scholars associating the start of the 50-day-count to a "Feast of First Fruits", but when reading Lev 23:6-14 and Exo 34:18-26 I rather see this as a small ceremony related to barley, without a "holy convocation" on this day which would make it a "Feast".

Meanwhile the end of the 50-day count includes indeed the term "first fruits", speaks of the much more important wheat, much more offerings and especially the "holy convocation" giving it the real character of a feast.

I do not want to add another name to Feast of Harvest and Pentecost, but I am confused why the start and not the end of the 50-day-count is called Feast of First Fruits.

My intention is to figure out which of both events (either barley/beginning or wheat/end) rather related to Christ being the First Fruit. Or is it that Christ and His resurrection simply relates to the 50 days of First Fruits?

*(But now Christ has been raised from the dead, the first fruits of those who have fallen asleep. 1Cor 15:20)*

Comment: I've no time now to answer but hope to do so later. In brief, the count in Lev. 23 started when a few stalks of grain ripened, enough to make up one sheaf. They were the harbinger of the full harvest when the main crop would have ripened, 50 days later. This one sheaf was presented at the temple, dedicated to God. This prefigured Christ as the first-fruit, ascending to heaven, then 50 days later came Pentecost when the harvest following began on earth.  The 'feast' aspect in the O.T. can then be understood, in light of Christ's ascension.

Comment: @Anne As your description, this would seem to relate closely to Prototokos in its true meaning (tokos = 'usury') that of the first return on an investment (in monetary terms) or the first harvesting from a planting. See p24 of '_The Only Begotten Son of God'_ on [my website](https://belmontpublications.co.uk/books/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start of this harvest-period is intrinsically linked to the end of it. One event marks the start, and another event marks the end, with a 50-day count inbetween both. The word 'feast' is used, and the time of year this took place was the Jewish first month of Abib, which corresponds to our March and April. The firstfruit was when a few stalks of grain ripened, enough to make up one sheaf. They were the harbinger of the full harvest when the main crop would have ripened, 50 days later. This one sheaf was presented at the temple, dedicated to God. The priest had to wave the sheaf before the Lord, and a burnt offering of a perfect lamb one year old made, along with its grain and wine offerings also (Leviticus 23:9-14).

The count in Leviticus 23:15-21 (known as the Feast of Weeks) started from the day after the Sabbath, the day that first sheaf of ripened grain had been waved before the Lord. Seven full weeks equaled 50 days, and was known as Pentecost. That was when all the Israelites were to then bring their own grain, lamb and drink offerings to the temple. Obviously, this was a massive gathering and a celebration, a feast.

The first, single sheaf prefigured Christ as the first-fruit, ascending to heaven, then 50 days later came Pentecost when the harvest following began on earth. On that one day alone, 3,000 converts to Christ were 'brought in' (harvested). This is where a look at the word applied to Jesus - *prototokos* - is revealing. As per the website link given in a comment above, I now quote from it:

> "Nine times is the word used in the Greek scriptures. The word does
> not mean 'first-begotten' nor does it - merely - convey the idea of a
> first bearing. Nor should it be confused, in translation or in
> concept, with the word *monogenes*...  in the nine times it is used,
> *prototokos* expresses the first fruit, the first return but in different contexts. The Person who is the Prototokos is seen to be
> such in different aspects, seven times. Twice, the word is used in a
> wider sense, once pre-figuratively and once in anticipation.
>
> ...The Prototokos was brought forth of Mary. He was The Son - of her.
> And Joseph, as he was commanded by an angel, called his name Jesus.
>
> This was the first indication of God's investment in creation. All
> that labour. All that patience. All that burdensome suffering of the
> vessels of wrath fitted for destruction. All the patient bearing with
> Israel in order to demonstrate his purposes on earth in artefact and
> ritual, before the coming of the Messiah.
>
> All of God's investment, now proved to be a viable project. For here
> was the first return of all that input. Here was the 'firstfruit' of
> that creation, The Prototokos.
>
> That creation - so lamentable in its failure - had now, at last,
> brought forth the first token of success. And his name was called
> Jesus, for he shall save his people from their sins." (*The Only
> Begotten Son of God*, Nigel Johnstone, pp24-25, Belmont Publications
> Ltd, 2019)

I hope this now enables clearer understanding of the significance of Christ, as the firstfruit, as per 1 Corinthians 15:20 -  ***"But now is Christ risen from the dead, and become the firstfruits of them that slept."*** **The firstfuit offering had to be made first, and it guaranteed the main harvest to follow.**

Answer (score 1):

OP:  My intention is to figure out which of both events (either barley/beginning or wheat/end) rather related to Christ being the First Fruit. Or is it that Christ and His resurrection simply relates to the 50 days of First Fruits?

There were three harvest feasts in the Old Testament, foreshadowing the New Covenant.

Barley (Passover)

> Speak unto the children of Israel, and say unto them, When ye be come into the land which I give unto you, and shall reap the harvest thereof, then ye shall bring a sheaf of the firstfruits of your harvest unto the priest: Lev 23:10

This speaks to Christ's resurrection.

> But now is Christ risen from the dead, and become the firstfruits of them that slept. 1 Cor 15:20

Wheat (Pentecost)

> Ye shall bring out of your habitations two wave loaves of two tenth deals: they shall be of fine flour; they shall be baken with leaven; they are the firstfruits unto the LORD. Lev 23:17

This speaks to the outpouring of the Spirit, which was made possible by Christ's death, burial, resurrection, and ascension.

> And not only they, but ourselves also, which have the firstfruits of the Spirit, even we ourselves groan within ourselves, waiting for the adoption, to wit, the redemption of our body. Romans 8:23

Ingathering (Tabernacles)

> Also in the fifteenth day of the seventh month, when ye have gathered in the fruit of the land, ye shall keep a feast unto the LORD seven days: on the first day shall be a sabbath, and on the eighth day shall be a sabbath. Lev 23:39

This has not occurred yet.

> And I saw a great white throne, and him that sat on it, from whose face the earth and the heaven fled away; and there was found no place for them. Rev 20:11

In short, Christ's resurrection occurred during Passover and may appear as a small event, but solely because of Christ's resurrection marking the start of the 50-day count, it makes possible the other two harvests, the outpouring of the Spirit beginning some 2,000 years ago and the future ingathering of all.